# SharePoint emails to Distribution Groups

Tags: email, notifications

I have some issues with receiving email notification with Distribution Groups.
The notification will received by individual users and Shared Mail Box but not with Distribution Groups. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint cannot send email to Distribution group because it doesn't have a valid email address associated.

The work around is setup a security group that is email enabled. SharePoint can send to this security group's email.

Comment: Thanks for your message, what about Shared Mail Box, can SP send the emails to Shared Mail Box?

Comment: Shared mailboxes have "email address" but not a "user". If your notification allow input an email address, it should work. If the function have to pick a "user", then it will not work.